# jssor onclick open larger version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

Is it possible using jssor to click on a photo in the slideshow and on click make it open a larger photo (responsive/mobile-friendly), e.g. in a popup?

Currently I'm using the following code:

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{ $Duration: 500, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, $Opacity: 2 } }];

        var options = {
            $FillMode: 1,
            $DragOrientation: 3,
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 5000,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('artikelphoto', options);
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div u="slides" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div><img u="image" src="/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img u="image" src="/2.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('artikelphoto', options);

function SliderClickEventHandler(slideIndex) {
    //open your large image here
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, SliderClickEventHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to get the image url instead of the slideIndex?

Comment: No, slide comes with any content, there may be no image.